Not creating the .g.dart class in Flutter(Dart)
I have used the json_serializable library in flutter and created a class and created the Annotation of the library i.e. json_serializable in the class as below example:
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'AppData.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class AppData {
  String? Username;
  String? Password;
  String? Avatar;
  String? Name;
  String? Family;
  String? FullName;
  String? UserType;
  String? Email;
  String? Mobile;

  AppData({this.Username, this.Password, this.Email,
    this.Family, this.Name, this.FullName, this.UserType, this.Mobile, this.Avatar})

  factory AppData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AppDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AppDataToJson(this);
}

The problem is that when I type dart run build_runner build -d in the terminal, it gives an error and does not create the AppData.g.dart class.
The error image it gives in the terminal:


as the message says: the reason is in the line #18 - your AppData ctor has syntax error

@pskink This is the code mentioned in the library itself. https://pub.dev

AppData belongs to json_serializable?

@pskink Not AppData is like Person in the example given. https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

@pskink Even in this tutorial, it does the same thing and creates the .g.dart class. https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=zjNhlmue5Os

in the example: Person({...});, in your code: AppData({...}) - you see the difference?

You are missing a semicolon to close the AppData constructor:
AppData({this.Username, this.Password, this.Email,this.Family, this.Name, this.FullName, this.UserType, this.Mobile, this.Avatar});
